# Is this space reflexive Banach space?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Set $$W=\Big\{ u:[0,+\infty )\to \mathbb{R} \; \text{is absolutely continuous and}\; u'\in L^2 [0,+\infty)\Big\},$$ where $q$ is a non-zero constant. Assume that $$X=\Big\{ u\in W:\int_0^{+\infty}(|u'(t)|^2+q^2 |u(t)|^2)dt<+\infty\Big\}$$ with the inner product $$\langle u,v\rangle:=\int_0^{+\infty}(u'(t)v'(t)+q^2u(t)v(t))dt$$ which induces the norm $$\|u\|:=\Big( \int_0^{+\infty}(|u'(t)|^2+q^2 |u(t)|^2)dt\Big)^{\frac{1}{2}}$$.

How can we prove that $X$ is a reflexive Banach space? This space is called the Sobolev space in the literature. Is there any proof for that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: it is a Hilbert space

Comment: @daw I could show that $\langle u,v\rangle$ is an inner product but my problem is that how to show $X$ is complete with the induced norm?

Comment: If $(u_n)$ is Cauchy in $X$, then $(u_n)$ and $(u_n')$ are Cauchy in $L^2$. You just need to prove that the limit of the derivative is the derivative of the limit.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven I got it. Thanks very much. I will show that.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven I could show that $(u_n)$ and $(u'_n )$ are Cauchy in $L^2$. So we have $u_n \to u$ and $u'_n \to v$ for $u,v\in L^2$. I understood that if we show that  the limit of the derivative is the derivative of the limit, then $u'=v$. Buw how can I show that?